# Doctrine2 Command Line Tool Causes Apache to Crash in XAMPP

Tags: xampp, doctrine-orm

running a command like `php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` or `php doctrine orm:schema-tool:drop --force` causes apache to "crash" and forces you to click start from within the xampp control panel.

This is not a huge issue because the command runs successfully ie. the tables are created/dropped, **THEN** apache crashes. It is just an annoyance.

FYI, I am using `64 bit` windows and I am using the command line tool from within a command window. This is possible because I added PHP to my path...

Comment: Why does apache crash when you call a script from the commandline? Seems weird to me.

Comment: But Apache server shouldn't be even involved when you use CLI. Please check both Apache and PHP logs.

Comment: I have the same problem. Of course this is weird, but it seems to be a problem with the xampp package. In the apache error log, I see that the apache child process exits with error code "1073807364" when I use PHP on the command line.